# Внедрение EJB в Сервлет java

Tags: java, servlet, dependency-injection, ejb

Здравствуйте мой проект maven имеет 3 модуля 1)ear 2)ejb 3)web
Как внедрить EJB сессионный бин из ejb модуля в сервлет модуля web?

myBean класс в ejb модуле

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "demodb") 
private EntityManager entityManager;
private Session session;

public MyBean(){

};
...
```

И Сервлет в web модуле в который нужно этот бин внедрить:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/servlet")
public class MyServlet extends AbstractHttpGetServlet {
@EJB 
private MyBean bean;
```

в результате этого ошибка при компиляции Cannot resolve symbvol MyBean
каким образом я должен сослаться на бин в другом модуле из сервлета?
Модули проекта:

[image: модули]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так

```
 @Stateless
 public class MyBeamImpl implements MyBean{

 }

 @Local
 public interface MyBean{

 }

 public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
      @EJB(mappedName = "myBean")
      private MyBean myBean;
 }
```

Comment: В каком модуле я должен описать локальный интерфейс?

Comment: Описывать нужно в ejb модуле

Comment: Да сработало спасибо! Возможно ли убрать добавленный интерфейс и применить аннотацию @Local к cамому бину?

Comment: Нет. Это должен быть именно интерфейс